# How to toggle between 2 responsive headers (mobile and desktop) using React and styled-components considering performance and advertisement displays?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Here's my situation: I've got 2 Header components which I need to toggle from/to Mobile and Desktop.

`<HeaderDesktop>`

- Logo
- Search bar
- Horizontal Navbar with dropdown menu

`<HeaderMobile>`

- Smaller logo
- Button to open Search bar
- SideNav with the display of an adsense advertisement

---

**MY CURRENT APPROACH**

Right now, what I'm doing to toggle between those two is:

At the `1200px` breakpoint, I toggle their displays from `none` to `flex` and vice-versa (see code below). This works as intended.

```
HeaderDesktopDIV = styled.div`
  display: none; 

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    display: flex;
  }
`;

HeaderMobileDIV = styled.div`
  display: flex;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

**MY CONCERN**

My concern is that both components are rendered by React. I can still inspect both elements on browser (see picture below).

This makes total sense, because they both exist and have been rendered by their parent component `Header`. The only thing keeping one of them out of the screen is a CSS rule with `display: none`.

This also might be considered a good thing, because the toggle between them is extremely fast.

**MY QUESTION**

**But what about performance?**

Is this a good practice? I mean, should I even be doing it like this? Is there another approach which might be more efficient? I mean, they're not expensive components, but what if they were?

**What about ads display?**

What if I have an advertisement placed on the `SideNav` which is only displayed on the Mobile version? Wouldn't it be an issue? That ad would be rendered on the Desktop version but it would be hidden from the user.

I mean, [Google adsense has a way of making the ads responsible too](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124#hide), but what I'm using another ad partner that doesn't?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach to toggle between the components,

```
{window.innerWidth > 1200 ? <HeaderDesktop> : <HeaderMobile>}
```

In this way you will get only one component at a time. And you will not need any `css` for this.

Answer (score 1):

First: If you have a heavy functional nav bar it will damage your performance.
You can solve it by creating a hoc(high order component) for desktop and hoc for mobile (or dynamic hoc that get ranges property) which will render the child component only if screen width fits.

Second: On Google Adsense it is againts policy! and your account might get blocked.
I guess it is the same for most of the advertising services.